# Core Data, mathematical operations in predicate

Tags: core-data

I have an entity called `Product` which has an attribute `orders` and an attribute `stock`. This is a one-to-many relation, which means a `Product` can have multiple `order`s.

Now I want to use `NSPredicate` to fetch products which satisfied `Number of orders - stock > 0`. What should I use for the `predicateWithFormat`?

This is what I did which is not working:
`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"orders.@count - stock > 0"];`

**Update 1:**
I changed the predicate to:
`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"orders.@count > stock"];`
This works fine. But still don't know why the original one is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To answer "still don't know why the original one is not working":

[Apple's Predicate Format String Syntax Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1) doesn't indicate that arithmetic is allowed.